# Grouping Restful Routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

Simply put, is there any way that you can group restful routes to avoid repetition? As my app expands I find myself listing routes as follows:

```
resources :users
resources :articles
resources :categories
...
```

What I'd like to do is group these resources together on one line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not seperate them using a comma like this:

`resources :users, :articles, :categories`

Comment: Coincidentally, I too discovered this simple technique a lot later than I should ideally have. :)